# Bug in review suggested edits in Chrome

Tags: bug

Usually when I open the Suggested Edit tab, but sometime also after coming back from improving a post, I can't see the suggested edit, only the original post.

[image]

Refreshing the page doesn't help; I just have to choose `Not Sure`, and the next post is shown correctly, two versions side by side.

**Note:** After more observations, it seems to happen each time a post dosen't have a block of code, only text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely, you will see that some of the tags are green and some are red. This means that the only thing changed were the tags, the edit doesn't include any changes in the post itself.

In this case it's useless to show you the exact same text two times, so you see just the post, and the tag changes indicated by the color.

Comment: So, you mean it's by-design that when there are only tag suggestions, it'll only show one post?

Comment: @Adinia, yes, exactly ;)